# Equivalent of or alternative to CGPathApply in Swift?

Tags: swift, cgpath

In the [pre-release documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply) there appears to be no Swift version of CGPathApply. Is there an equivalent or alternative? I'm trying to get all subpaths of a CGPath so that I can redraw it from a different starting point.

Comment: Have you tried it anyway? I've seen some other symbols that are actually available in Swift failing to show up as Swift in the docs. Also try cmd-clicking another CGPath function and see what shows up in the Swift-translated module "header". And if it's not there, [file a bug](http://bugreport.apple.com) — it should be.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Since Late 2017

Starting with iOS 11, macOS 10.13, tvOS 11, and watchOS 4, you should use the `CGPath`'s `applyWithBlock` method. Here is [a real example](https://github.com/mayoff/RoundedPath/blob/69a138eb0dde7a3161b0242912f66636840cd2fe/Sources/RoundedPath/CGPath.rounded.swift#L58-L93) taken from [this Swift package that rounds the corners of a `CGPath`](https://github.com/mayoff/RoundedPath). In this code, `self` is a `CGPath`:

```
self.applyWithBlock {
    let points = $0.pointee.points

    switch $0.pointee.type {
    case .moveToPoint:
        if let currentSubpath, !currentSubpath.segments.isEmpty {
            copy.append(currentSubpath, withCornerRadius: radius)
        }
        currentSubpath = .init(firstPoint: points[0])
        currentPoint = points[0]

    case .addLineToPoint:
        append(.line(start: currentPoint, end: points[0]))
        currentPoint = points[0]

    case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
        append(.quad(points[0], end: points[1]))
        currentPoint = points[1]

    case .addCurveToPoint:
        append(.cubic(points[0], points[1], end: points[2]))
        currentPoint = points[2]

    case .closeSubpath:
        if var currentSubpath {
            currentSubpath.segments.append(.line(start: currentPoint, end: currentSubpath.firstPoint))
            currentSubpath.isClosed = true
            copy.append(currentSubpath, withCornerRadius: radius)
            currentPoint = currentSubpath.firstPoint
        }
        currentSubpath = nil

    @unknown default:
        break
    }
}
```

#### Swift 3.0

In Swift 3.0, you can use `CGPath.apply` like this:

```
let path: CGPath = ...
// or let path: CGMutablePath

path.apply(info: nil) { (_, elementPointer) in
    let element = elementPointer.pointee
    let command: String
    let pointCount: Int
    switch element.type {
    case .moveToPoint: command = "moveTo"; pointCount = 1
    case .addLineToPoint: command = "lineTo"; pointCount = 1
    case .addQuadCurveToPoint: command = "quadCurveTo"; pointCount = 2
    case .addCurveToPoint: command = "curveTo"; pointCount = 3
    case .closeSubpath: command = "close"; pointCount = 0
    }
    let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: pointCount))
    Swift.print("\(command) \(points)")
}
```

#### Swift 2.2

With the addition of `@convention(c)`, you can now call `CGPathApply` directly from Swift. Here's a wrapper that does the necessary magic:

```
extension CGPath {
    func forEach(@noescape body: @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
        typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
        func callback(info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, element: UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) {
            let body = unsafeBitCast(info, Body.self)
            body(element.memory)
        }
        print(sizeofValue(body))
        let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)
        CGPathApply(self, unsafeBody, callback)
    }
}
```

(Note that `@convention(c)` isn't mentioned in my code, but is used in the declaration of `CGPathApply` in the Core Graphics module.)

Example usage:

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 100), cornerRadius: 15)
path.CGPath.forEach { element in
    switch (element.type) {
    case CGPathElementType.MoveToPoint:
        print("move(\(element.points[0]))")
    case .AddLineToPoint:
        print("line(\(element.points[0]))")
    case .AddQuadCurveToPoint:
        print("quadCurve(\(element.points[0]), \(element.points[1]))")
    case .AddCurveToPoint:
        print("curve(\(element.points[0]), \(element.points[1]), \(element.points[2]))")
    case .CloseSubpath:
        print("close()")
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that the type of "element" in Swift is UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>

Comment: Ole Begemann just published an excellent post on this topic http://oleb.net/blog/2015/06/c-callbacks-in-swift/.

Comment: Why is the second argument a block? The docs say "A pointer to the user data that Quartz will pass to the function being applied, or NULL.". I am trying to convert to swift some code that passes an array in that parameter.

Comment: The second argument is a block because a block encapsulates code and data. You can pass a block that refers to an array.

Answer (score 11):

(Hint: if you have to support an iOS before iOS 11, use the accepted answer. If you can require iOS 11, this answer is much easier.)

Since **iOS 11**, there is an official answer from Apple to this question: `CGPath.applyWithBlock(_:)`.

This makes all the dirty tricks unnecessary that come from the problem that `CGPath.apply(info:function:)` is a C function that does not allow information transported in and out of the function in a usual swifty way.

The following code allows you to do:

```
let pathElements = path.pathElements()
```

To be able to do that, copy & paste

```
import CoreGraphics

extension CGPath {
    func pathElements() -> [PathElement] {
        
        var result = [PathElement]()

        self.applyWithBlock { (elementPointer) in
            let element = elementPointer.pointee
            switch element.type {
            case .moveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 1))
                let el = PathElement.moveToPoint(points[0])
                result.append(el)
            case .addLineToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 1))
                let el = PathElement.addLineToPoint(points[0])
                result.append(el)
            case .addQuadCurveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 2))
                let el = PathElement.addQuadCurveToPoint(points[0], points[1])
                result.append(el)
            case .addCurveToPoint:
                let points = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: element.points, count: 3))
                let el = PathElement.addCurveToPoint(points[0], points[1], points[2])
                result.append(el)
            case .closeSubpath:
                result.append(.closeSubpath)
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
        
        return result
    }

}

public enum PathElement {

    case moveToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addLineToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case addCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case closeSubpath

}
```

or take this code as an example to how to use `CGPath.applyWithBlock(_:)` yourself.

For completeness, this is the official documentation from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgpath/2873218-applywithblock

Since **iOS 13** there is an even more elegant official answer from Apple: Use `SwiftUI` (even if your UI isn't in `SwiftUI`)

Transform your `cgPath` into a `SwiftUI Path`

```
let cgPath = CGPath(ellipseIn: rect, transform: nil)
let path =  Path(cgPath)
path.forEach { element in
    switch element {
    case .move(let to):
        break
    case .line(let to):
        break
    case .quadCurve(let to, let control):
        break
    case .curve(let to, let control1, let control2):
        break
    case .closeSubpath:
        break
    }
}
```

Variable `element` is of type Path.Element which is a pure Swift Enum, so there aren't even tricks necessary to get the values out of element.

For completeness, this is th official Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/3059547-foreach

Answer (score 7):

Here's the highlights from Ole Begemann's [great post](http://oleb.net/blog/2015/06/c-callbacks-in-swift/) (thanks @Gouldsc!), adapted for Swift 3, which allows for accessing the individual elements composing a `UIBezierPath` instance:

```
extension UIBezierPath {

    var elements: [PathElement] {
        var pathElements = [PathElement]()
        withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &pathElements) { elementsPointer in
            cgPath.apply(info: elementsPointer) { (userInfo, nextElementPointer) in
                let nextElement = PathElement(element: nextElementPointer.pointee)
                let elementsPointer = userInfo!.assumingMemoryBound(to: [PathElement].self)
                elementsPointer.pointee.append(nextElement)
            }
        }
        return pathElements
    }

}

public enum PathElement {

    case moveToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addLineToPoint(CGPoint)
    case addQuadCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case addCurveToPoint(CGPoint, CGPoint, CGPoint)
    case closeSubpath

    init(element: CGPathElement) {
        switch element.type {
        case .moveToPoint: self = .moveToPoint(element.points[0])
        case .addLineToPoint: self = .addLineToPoint(element.points[0])
        case .addQuadCurveToPoint: self = .addQuadCurveToPoint(element.points[0], element.points[1])
        case .addCurveToPoint: self = .addCurveToPoint(element.points[0], element.points[1], element.points[2])
        case .closeSubpath: self = .closeSubpath
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: adding a usage sample would make this a better answer.

Comment: I wonder is it possible to clear some of the points and create a separate UIBezierPath using remaining element points? Basically I want to erase some of the paths from original bezierPath. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Dmitry Rodionov has produced a function for converting a Swift function to a CFunctionPointer (see https://github.com/rodionovd/SWRoute/wiki/Function-hooking-in-Swift).

```html
#define kObjectFieldOffset sizeof(uintptr_t)

struct swift_func_object {
    uintptr_t *original_type_ptr;
#if defined(__x86_64__)
    uintptr_t *unknown0;
#else
    uintptr_t *unknown0, *unknown1;
#endif
    uintptr_t function_address;
    uintptr_t *self;
};


uintptr_t _rd_get_func_impl(void *func)
{
    struct swift_func_object *obj = (struct swift_func_object *)*(uintptr_t *)(func + kObjectFieldOffset);
    
    //printf("-->Address of C-Func %lx unk=%lx ori=%lx<--\n", obj->function_address, obj->unknown0, obj->original_type_ptr);
    return obj->function_address;
}
```

I am using this successfully with CGPathApply along with a Swift callback function. (code at http://parker-liddle.org/CGPathApply/CGPathApply.zip)
Although as Dmitry says this is a reverse engineered function and not a supported one.

Comment: Wow! That's some really cool hackery! I think there are other ways to achieve it now that don't require going to that depth, but it's great to see people having that kind of facility and pulling things like that off in the face of dire coding adversity!