# Get the start point of a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I created a UIBezierPath but I don't know how to access the start point of it. I tried doing this:

```
let startPoint = path.currentPoint
```

The property `currentPoint` gives me the last point, not the start point. The reason I need the start point is because I want to place an image at the starting point of the path.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to drop down to `CGPath` and use `CGPathApply` to walk the elements. You only want the first one, but you have to look at them all.

I'm assuming that your path is well-formed, and starts with a "move." That should always be true for a `UIBezierPath` (I'm not aware of any way to make it not be true.)

You'll need some help from rob mayoff's [`CGPath.forEach`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26307538/97337), which is quite tricky, but with that in place it's pretty straightforward:

```
// rob mayoff's CGPath.foreach
extension CGPath {
    func forEach(@noescape body: @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
        typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
        func callback(info: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, element: UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) {
            let body = unsafeBitCast(info, Body.self)
            body(element.memory)
        }
        let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>.self)
        CGPathApply(self, unsafeBody, callback)
    }
}

// Finds the first point in a path
extension UIBezierPath {
    func firstPoint() -> CGPoint? {
        var firstPoint: CGPoint? = nil

        self.CGPath.forEach { element in
            // Just want the first one, but we have to look at everything
            guard firstPoint == nil else { return }
            assert(element.type == .MoveToPoint, "Expected the first point to be a move")
            firstPoint = element.points.memory
        }
        return firstPoint
    }
}
```

---

In Swift 3, it's basically the same:

```
// rob mayoff's CGPath.foreach
extension CGPath {
    func forEach( body: @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void) {
        typealias Body = @convention(block) (CGPathElement) -> Void
        func callback(info: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?, element: UnsafePointer<CGPathElement>) {
            let body = unsafeBitCast(info, to: Body.self)
            body(element.pointee)
        }
        let unsafeBody = unsafeBitCast(body, to: UnsafeMutableRawPointer.self)
        self.apply(info: unsafeBody, function: callback)
    }
}

// Finds the first point in a path
extension UIBezierPath {
    func firstPoint() -> CGPoint? {
        var firstPoint: CGPoint? = nil

        self.cgPath.forEach { element in
            // Just want the first one, but we have to look at everything
            guard firstPoint == nil else { return }
            assert(element.type == .moveToPoint, "Expected the first point to be a move")
            firstPoint = element.points.pointee
        }
        return firstPoint
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks it works!!! I have yet another problem and asked a different question. could you look at it and see if you can answer? Heres the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36705072/dynamically-change-position-based-on-scrollview

Comment: Hi, I used Xcode to convert this code to Swift 3.0. I am now getting a crash on this line, which Xcode changed: `apply(info: unsafeBody, function: callback as! CGPathApplierFunction)`. Unfortunately there is nothing in the debugger but this appears `thread 1 exc_bad_instruction(code=exc_1386_invop subcode=0x0)`. My research says that it is due to force unwrapping (in this case force casting). If I try to safely cast, then I get a `Segmentation fault: 11`. Any suggestions?

Comment: The type of `CGPathApplierFunction` changed. It now takes a `UnsafeMutableRawPointer?`. You have to change the signature of `callback` to match, not just force-cast it.

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is

-Subclass the UIBezierPath

-Create the custom property as startPoint

-Override the moveToPoint method and set value for startPoint there

```
class MyBezierPath: UIBezierPath {
    var startPoint :CGPoint?

    override func moveToPoint(point: CGPoint) {
        super.moveToPoint(point)
        startPoint=point;
    }
}

    var myBezier = MyBezierPath()
    myBezier.moveToPoint(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
    myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0))
    myBezier.addLineToPoint(CGPoint(x: 50, y: 100))
```

Comment: Why do we search for start point  if we jus set its value in the moveToPoint function?

Comment: @AlexKosyakov you might have start with path.addArc(...) for example.

Comment: @VladimirShutyuk got it, tnx!

Comment: Is there any similar workaround for finding the end point of a bezierPath.

Comment: @Frankenxtein uibezierpath.currentPoint will give you the end point.